# Moving from Subscription to Paid app model on the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

Can you move from a subscription model to a paid app model (paying upfront before downloading the app)?

My question is essentially if the users that downloaded the app as a "free" app with in app purchases option, would be able to download the app if they move to another device for example. Would it consider like they "own" the app and therefore would be able to download it again?
Or since it's now a "paid" app they won't be able to download it since they didn't pay upfront although they purchased a subscription through in app purchases?

Comment: Users who have previously downloaded the app "own" it forever. They can install the app, without charge, on any future devices. Effectively you are making a price change. If you increase the price existing users don't have to pay the difference. If you decrease the price they don't get the difference refunded.